# Exposing object to view through the interface

Tags: vba, ms-access, mvp

In MVP, is it valid to expose an object (through the interface) to the view instead of setting up individual properties for each control?

For example, I have an object `Customer`.

**Customer Class**

```
Private this As TCustomer
Private Type TCustomer
    FirstName As String
    LastName As String
    Email As String
End Type

Public Property Get FirstName() As String
    FirstName = this.FirstName
End Property
Public Property Let FirstName(ByVal Value As String)
    this.FirstName = Value
End Property

Public Property Get LastName() As String
    LastName = this.LastName
End Property
Public Property Let LastName(ByVal Value As String)
    this.LastName = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Email() As String
    Email = this.Email
End Property
Public Property Let Email(ByVal Value As String)
    this.Email = Value
End Property
```

Exposing the `Customer` object through the interface.

**ICustomerView Interface**

```
Public Sub UpdateFromCustomer(ByVal Customer As Customer)
End Sub

Public Sub ReadToCustomer(ByVal Customer As Customer)
End Sub
```

The Form implementing the interface:

```
Implements ICustomerView

Private p As Presenter

Private Sub ICustomerView_UpdateFromCustomer(ByVal Customer As Customer)
    With Customer
        TextFirstName.Value = .FirstName
        TextLastName.Value = .LastName
        TextEmail.Value = .Email
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub ICustomerView_ReadToCustomer(ByVal Customer As Customer)
    With Customer
        .FirstName = TextFirstName.Value
        .LastName = TextLastName.Value
        .Email = TextEmail.Value
    End With
End Sub

'Example written in Excel
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Set p = New Presenter
    Set p.View = Me
        p.Find
        p.Save
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()
    Set p = Nothing
End Sub
```

**Presenter Class**

```
Private m_view As ICustomerView
Private m_model As Model

Public Property Set View(ByVal obj As ICustomerView)
    Set m_view = obj
End Property

Public Sub Find()

    Dim cust As Customer
    Set cust = m_model.DummyCustomer()

    m_view.UpdateFromCustomer cust
End Sub

Public Sub Save()

    Dim cust As Customer
    Set cust = New Customer

    m_view.ReadToCustomer cust
    m_model.SaveCustomer cust
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set m_model = New Model
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set m_view = Nothing
    Set m_model = Nothing
End Sub
```

Lastly, a dummy model:

```
Public Function DummyCustomer() As Customer

    Dim obj As Customer
    Set obj = New Customer

    With obj
        .FirstName = "some value 1"
        .LastName = "some value 2"
        .Email = "some value 3"
    End With

    Set DummyCustomer = obj
End Function

Public Sub SaveCustomer(ByVal Customer As Customer)
    If IsValid(Customer) Then InternalSave Customer
End Sub

Private Function IsValid(obj As Customer) As Boolean
    IsValid = Len(obj.FirstName) > 0 And _
              Len(obj.LastName) > 0 And _
              Len(obj.Email) > 0
End Function

Private Sub InternalSave(Customer As Customer)
    Debug.Print Customer.FirstName
    Debug.Print Customer.LastName
    Debug.Print Customer.Email
End Sub
```

If I create an interface with a get/set property for each control in the view, I will have two classes, the concrete `Customer` class and the `ICustomerView` interface with the exact same properties.

To avoid this duplication, could the above approach be considered as a valid alternative?

Comment: Seems the View and the Presenter relationship is upside down - the Presenter would know about both the View and the Model, but the View would only know about the Model. The presenter should be responsible for creating the View, not the other way around. Otherwise, +1 and favorited, and huge kudos for pushing VBA to the next level!

Comment: @Mathieu Guindon Thanks Mathieu. I use the above in Access where the main form is loaded as soon as the application loads (through the property load form at startup) so I treat the main form as an entry point.

Comment: Oh.. that does complicate things a bit.

Comment: Have a look at [Interfaces in VBA - How to use them and how to work around them](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/30739/Interfaces-in-VBA-How-to-use-them-and-how-to-work-around-them.html) seems like there are some traps.

Comment: @ComputerVersteher that link lost me at "The purpose of CCInterface is to completely replace the standard interface technology built in into VBA. Not that the interfaces which you can insert into your code using the "Implements" statement are not a really useful technology" - whoever wrote this doesn't understand COM. Or maybe they do. But in any case VBA "interfaces" without the `Implements` keyword are not COM interfaces that VBA can understand as such.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon you are sure? I know, you have deep insights (Rubberduck-VBA rules!) to vba, but Bitsqueezer is one of the best german Access programmers I think. I don't knoew enought to jugde this. but it would surprise me if he is wrong. Maybe a good first question for me, where it can be dicusst (or better in a chat?).

Comment: @ComputerVersteher I guess I knee-jerked at the intro. I use interfaces all the time, and claiming they're downright useless struck me as a blatantly ignorant statement. Skimming through the rest of the article, seems he knows his stuff - but IMO that work-around is rejecting the single most powerful feature of VBA, only because of some alledged instability. FWIW I've witnessed the same in Excel - whatever you do, don't use `Implements` in a worksheet module - but there are better work-arounds that don't involve ditching `Implements` altogether.

Comment: @ComputerVersteher so I finally read the whole thing. The article glosses over the single most powerful and useful thing interfaces enable - polymorphism - and seems to force rather obstrusive changes in every bit of code that works with interfaces in order for the thing to just work. Real interfaces don't force any late binding (calls against `Object`), enable polymorphism in a very straightforward way, and are recognized as such by static code analysis tools. Again I don't do much Access, and the guy is certainly experienced, but I disagree with his assessment of how broken interfaces are.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon `polymorphism `? What the ,,,, OK I have a lot of things to discover, In return for your efforts RD will receive addtional german translations (if not done yet) I will ask him for a sample, I think he would be interested in better solutions and I am interested in pay-back knowledge to him, as he gives a lot of support to thode that need help in Access, The usual post is at leadt half the article,

Comment: @ComputerVersteher you know, as I re-read the bit I quoted earlier *carefully*, I think the double-negative phrasing threw me off... If what he actually means is that "the interfaces which you can insert into your code using the "Implements" statement *are* a really useful technology", I can't disagree with that... but the problem with interfaces isn't that they're broken. IME it's trying to use `Implements` on a *document* class module, an object only the host app (Excel, Access, etc.) knows how to create and initialize. And since Access forms are *document* class modules...

Comment: What kind of answer do you seek here? If you want a full review of your code, codereview might be a better place. The code looks valid to me.

Comment: The question is in relation to the MVP pattern and the notion of passing concrete objects from/to the view. Don't require code review, this is just a simple example to illustrate my point.